# How i can benefit from asp.net mvc knowledge when building a SharePoint web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sharepoint

I am going to start a new project that include building a web application for a company that provide  technical support services from fixing Pc, laptops, operating system installation, etc.

the web site will allow users to view available products and services and they can also login to the web application to view the status of their order (such as purchase order, fixing a server, etc).

i have a team of three developers and we were developing web sites and web applications using asp.net MVC. The client was interested in building a SharePoint web application, and as i and my team did NOT work on SharePoint before; So my question is will we be able to benefit from our knowledge in the following areas:-

1. asp.net mvc including -but not limited to - (mvc security (such as anti forgery tokens, authorization tokens,etc), mvc routing, model binding, asp.net mvc ajax (ajax.actionlinks .etc))
2. C#
3. ADO.Net Entity framework.
4. Razor view

if we decide to go with the SharePoint approach, Or our knowledge in asp.net mvc will not help us a lot in the SharePoint 2013 OR 2010 project?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is a platform built on ASP.NET and C#. Your ASP.NET and C# skills form the bare minimum required to start learning SharePoint.

Be warned that SharePoint is a massive product and the time to acquire enough SharePoint knowledge to succesfully complete your project will be great.

Knowing MVC is not enough to deliver a SharePoint solution correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If parts of your solution require custom development, your C#/ASP.Net knowledge will be useful. The preferred goal when developing SharePoint applications though, is to use the tools available to you with SharePoint, and go to custom development as a last resort.

You will have a fairly steep learning curve to develop a proper SharePoint application. If there is no other need for SharePoint other than this application, you're probably best off just making it as a pure MVC app.